# Is it possiblem to remove span which is automattically added by jquerymobiles?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobiles 1.4.2.
In my page i have used

```
<div data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-r" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-inset="true">
            <h3>¿Cuánto tiempo puede estar publicado un anuncio?</h3>

            some text
      </div>
```

When i run this code it converts this to

```
<div data-inset="true" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon wr ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed ui-first-child" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" data-collapsed-icon="carat-r" data-role="collapsible">
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
<a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit" href="#">

 Estoy interesado en una propiedad 
  <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>   </a></h3>
 <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">

           some text<b>"Solicitar más Información"</b> del anuncio que le interesa.
        </div></div>
```

It automatically adds the

```
<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status">  click to expand contents</span>.
```

Is it possible to remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove what?

If you want to remove just inner text: "click to expand contents" then add **data-expand-cue-text=""** attribute to your **data-role="collapsible"** <div>.

If you want to remove whole span you need to do it programatically like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('.ui-collapsible-heading-status').remove();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vds2U/59/

Third solution would require direct changes in framework.